# Generate a dialog box, in a single controller. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I made this code based on a tutorial. I want to know how I can use a single controller. I want to generate this dialog box, using only a controller.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/adnu6mmt/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=adnu6mmt

In this project I currently use 2 controllers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to save the modal instance and use it in the same controller. First you need to change your html like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Modal title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Modal content
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="close(true)">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="close(false)">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="button" value="Show modal" ng-click="showModal()"/>
</div>
```

And then in your controller:

```
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $modal) {

    var modalInstance = null;

    $scope.close = function (ok, hide) {
        if(ok) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            alert('cancel');
        }

        modalInstance.dismiss();
    };

    var modalScope = $scope.$new();

    $scope.showModal = function() {    
         modalInstance = $modal.open({
             templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
             scope: modalScope
         });
    }
});
```

When you want to control the modal in the same controller you need to have access to it, notice we are storing the result of the `$modal` in a variable for later use.

That is equal to injecting `modalInstance` to the other controller which lets you access `close`, `dismiss` or other functions on that object.

Comment: can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271985/close-all-dialog-boxes-in-angular-js-with-bootstrap